# OpenCV: goodFeaturesToTrack and calcOpticalFlowPyrLK for moving camera

Tags: opencv, opticalflow

I tried the code written here:
http://i-vizon.blogspot.ch/2013/03/optical-flow-using-opencv-library-on.html

It works pretty well, but does not perform well in the case of moving camera, because all features are removed on scene change.

Fundamentally the code is so composed:

- First frame: goodFeaturesToTrack(grayFrames,points1,MAX_COUNT,0.01,5,Mat(),3,0,0.04);
- Other frames:
  calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prevGrayFrame,grayFrames,points2,points1,status,err,winSize,3,termcrit,0,0.001);
  goodFeaturesToTrack(grayFrames,points1,MAX_COUNT,0.01,10,Mat(),3,0,0.04);
  with the swapping of points and copy of the current frame in the previous.

Problem:
when I use it with camera, handling it on my hand, when I change the first scenes no optical flow is produced, I suppose because initial features are not more contained in the new frames.
How I can refresh the feature point in this code to continue working?
Which is a good refresh condition? Based for example on the the number of features?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the purpose of using opticalflow? What are you trying to achieve in your application? Give us some background..

Comment: In a first step I just want to track optical flow for a moving camera. The algorithm indicated in the link just works well on steady camera (as for example a web-cam).

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use goodFeaturesToTrack? Will a constant grid work for you? In addition you might want to include your code to the question.

Comment: Thanks Sarid for the answer. I think I will use a constant grid.